# How to permanently assign a virtual drive letter in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-drive

In many applications, such as PowerISO, CyberLink Power2Go (the Virtual Drive Manager), etc. you can assign one or more fixed drive letters for virtual drives in Windows (e.g. `V:\`).

Because Windows 10 (already) supports virtual drives natively, I do not install external tools anymore. However, I cannot assign the drive-letter `V:\` permanently as a (kinda "reserved") virtual drive letter. Through Disk Management you can change the drive letter only temporary (until you eject the drive).

Is there a way to permanently assign a virtual drive letter in Windows 10?

Comment: GO back to using your utilities, Microsoft's implementation is half baked.

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to change Windows 10 default drives. It can be tricky to get back to default if you change the assignments.

Comment: After you set the drive letter in Disk Management or `DiskPart`, if you reboot right afterwards, is the drive letter still assigned upon logging back in _(if you're using Fast Startup, don't reboot - instead shutdown then boot back up)_?  If it's not, and there's not an option in the settings of those 3rd party programs to assign a drive letter, you'll likely have to set a task in Task Scheduler to mount the virtual drive as `V:` upon boot or login.